# From Date To Date Validation in DateEdit

Tags: jquery, date, validation

I am using Devexpress Control **DateEdit**
Can any one help me on From Date and Todate Validation for DateEdit
I can achieve same using JQuery But not sure in DateEdit on Devex

Validation Should be:

**From date should be less than to date**

**User should not select todate less than fromdate**

JavaScript

```
<script>
        function DateChanged() {


            var objFromDate = document.getElementById("deFromDate").value;
            var objToDate = document.getElementById("deToDate").value;

            var date1 = new Date(objFromDate);
            var date2 = new Date(objToDate);

            var date3 = new Date();
            var date4 = date3.getMonth() + "/" + date3.getDay() + "/" + date3.getYear();
            var currentDate = new Date(date4);

            if (date1 > date2) {
                alert("fromdate should be less than todate");
                return false;
            }
            else if (date1 > currentDate) {
                alert("From Date should be less than current date");
                return false;
            }
            else if (date2 > currentDate) {
                alert("To Date should be less than current date");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

But on console window i Getting error Like

**Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference**

So the Question is `.value` is not javascript function,

How can I retrieve selected Date Value

ASPX

```
<td>
  <dx:ASPxDateEdit CssClass="date" ID="deFromDate" runat="server" Width="117px" AllowUserInput="False" Height="25px"
  EditFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy" DisplayFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy" EditFormat="Custom"
  Theme="Office2003Blue" ClientInstanceName="deFromDate" OnInit="deFromDate_Init">
    <DropDownButton Image-Url="../Images/calendar.png" Image-Height="23px" Image-Width="23px"></DropDownButton>
   </dx:ASPxDateEdit>

       <dx:ASPxDateEdit CssClass="date" ID="deToDate" runat="server" Width="117px" AllowUserInput="False" Height="25px"
           EditFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy" DisplayFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy" EditFormat="Custom"
           Theme="Office2003Blue" ClientInstanceName="deQuoDate" OnInit="deToDate_Init">
             <DropDownButton Image-Url="../Images/calendar.png" Image-Height="23px" Image-Width="23px"></DropDownButton>
          </dx:ASPxDateEdit>
     <span><img src="/Images/icon_required_field.gif" /></span>
```

Comment: Is it case sensitive? Your script is looking for deFromdate, but your element is deFromDate

Comment: Yes you are correct but when i cahnged again its showing  Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference. Then How can i Get value of selected date

Comment: How do you call DateChanged()?